# Fee management ERP project

Tags: django-models, django-admin

i want to calculate the fee of a student and the student gets three options ie full payment,2 time payment,3 time payment after the calculation it should from receipt for those fees

in the admin i need to see each persons details and it should show a link and when that link is clicked it should show receipts if the person had selected 2 time payment the total amount should be divided into two and there should be 2 receipt 1st one for 1st installment and other one for 2ed installment